# Creating users from a csv file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

It's my first time in PowerShell to create users from a csv file. I am using a code from a tutorial I've watched, it's working on the when demonstrated on the video but, I can't make it work..

```
$ou=[ADSI] "LDAP:/..."
$dataSource = import-csv ".."

foreach($dataRecord in $dataSource) 
{

  $cn = $dataRecord.cn
  $sAMAccountName = $dataRecord.sAMAccountName
  $givenName = $dataRecord.FirstName
  $sn = $dataRecord.LastName
  $displayName = $sn + ", " + $givenName
  $userPrincipalName = $givenName + "." + $sn + "@nuggetlab.com"
  $newUser =  $ou.Create("user", "cn=" + $cn)

  $newUser.Put("sAMAccountName", $sAMAccountName)
  $newUser.Put("userPrincipalName", $userPrincipalName)
  $newUser.Put("displayName", $displayName)
  $newUser.Put("givenName", $givenName)
  $newUser.SetInfo()
  $newUser.SetPassword("Password")
  $newUser.psbase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
  $newUser.Put("company", "The Fantastic Four")
  $newUser.SetInfo()
}
```

The error says:

```
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" arguments(s): "The specified directory service or value does not exist"
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\CreateGroup.ps1:18 char18
+   $newUser.SetInfo <<<< ()
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MehthodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Comment: it's working now, it's embarrasing but my error was caused only by typo. The code above is working

Comment: You should post that, as an answer, then mark it accepted.

Comment: It would appear you are using the Powershell ADSI method for creating users. Microsoft has since shipped Powershell v2 and their Active Directory cmdlets that allow you to create users without ADSI.

TechNet AD Cmdlets docs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx
Technet getting started docs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg299328.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
$ou=[ADSI] "LDAP:/..."
$dataSource = import-csv ".."

foreach($dataRecord in $dataSource) 
{

  $cn = $dataRecord.cn
  $sAMAccountName = $dataRecord.sAMAccountName
  $givenName = $dataRecord.FirstName
  $sn = $dataRecord.LastName
  $displayName = $sn + ", " + $givenName
  $userPrincipalName = $givenName + "." + $sn + "@nuggetlab.com"
  $newUser =  $ou.Create("user", "cn=" + $cn)

  $newUser.Put("sAMAccountName", $sAMAccountName)
  $newUser.Put("userPrincipalName", $userPrincipalName)
  $newUser.Put("displayName", $displayName)
  $newUser.Put("givenName", $givenName)
  $newUser.SetInfo()
  $newUser.SetPassword("Password")
  $newUser.psbase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
  $newUser.Put("company", "The Fantastic Four")
  $newUser.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark this as accepted